# Overriding nginx deny rule for acme related block

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I have following nginx server config:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to proxy.
            try_files /maintenance.php $uri @proxyPass;
    }

    location @proxyPass {
            proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/acme;

    include /etc/nginx/expires.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/acme:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    allow myip;                           # my ip
    allow serverip;                       # server ip
    allow 66.133.109.36/32;               # allow outbound1.letsencrypt.org
    allow 64.78.149.164/32;               # allow outbound2.letsencrypt.org
    allow 64.78.149.164/32;               # allow outbound2.letsencrypt.org
    deny all;                             # deny everything else

    alias /srv/letsencrypt/acme-challenge/;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

the `deny all` rule for all which starts from dot conflicts with the rule for acme. If I remove it when I am able to access files in acme related folder otherwise I'm getting 403 Forbidden

I tried to set `allow all` instead of enlisting IP addresses in acme related location block like it is described in:
[Overriding nginx deny rule for a single location block](https://serverfault.com/questions/597022/overriding-nginx-deny-rule-for-a-single-location-block)
But id does not help

How to make those two location blocks to work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular-expression location blocks, like your deny rule, normally take precedence over prefix matches in nginx.

Prevent the regex check and have the prefix match take priority by adding `^~` to your block definition:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
```